# Hibernate Annotations with a collection

Tags: java, hibernate, configuration, collections, annotations

I am trying to implement my model using hibernate annotations.  I have 3 classes, image, person, and tags.  Tags is a a table consisting of 4 fields, an id, personId, imageId, and a createdDate.  Person has the fields name, id, birthdate, etc.  My image class is defined as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Image")
public class Image {
    private Integer imageId;
    private  Set<Person> persons = new HashSet<Person>();

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    public Integer getImageId() {
        return imageId;
    }

    public void setImageId(Integer imageId) {
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="Tags",
                joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="imageId", nullable=false)},
                inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="personId", nullable=false)})
    public Set<Person> getPersons() {
        return persons;
    }

    public void setPersons(Set<Person> persons) {
        this.persons = persons;
    }
```

If I remove the annotations on the getPersons() method I can use the classes and add and remove records.  I want to fetch all the tags with the image and I am trying to use a set.  I keep getting the following error:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException - failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.exmaple.persons, no session or session was closed
```

Can someone please help me and let me know what I am doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error message - which actually has nothing to do with your association mapping strategy or annotations - means that you have attempted to access a lazy-loaded collection on one of your domain objects after the `Session` was closed.

The solution is to either disable lazy-loading for this collection, explicitly load the collection before the `Session` is closed (for example, by calling `foo.getBars().size()`), or making sure that the `Session` stays open until it is no longer needed.

If you are not sure what lazy-loading is, [here is the section in the Hibernate manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-lazy).

Comment: Im going to accept this answer.  I appreciate the help.  I am still reading chapters 10 and 13 in the spring documentation.  I will post updates when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response matt.  I am confused now.  My query to retrieve the image looks like this:

```
public Image findByImageId(Integer imageId) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Image> images = hibernateTemplate.find(
            "from Image where imageId=?", imageId);
    return (Image)images.get(0);
}
```

I thought that I can call the single hql query and if my mappings are correct it will bring back the associated data.

I was looking at this example at this link [hibernate mappings](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-association):

```
2.2.5.3.1.3. Unidirectional with join table
A unidirectional one to many with join table is much preferred. This association is described through an @JoinTable.

@Entity
public class Trainer {
    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name="TrainedMonkeys",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="trainer_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="monkey_id")
    )
    public Set<Monkey> getTrainedMonkeys() {
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Monkey {
    ... //no bidir
}         Trainer describes a unidirectional relationship with Monkey using the join table TrainedMonkeys, with a foreign key trainer_id to Trainer (joinColumns) and a foreign key monkey_id to Monkey (inversejoinColumns).
```

Comment: Does anyone have any additional comments on my follow up question?  Thank you

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you are asking here, but your query to return the first `Image` instance would in fact return the object - but Hibernate is lazy loading the `Image.trainers` collection, which the error message refers to. This is the collection that you must load before closing the session, or mark as non-lazy-loaded.

Comment: I think that is where I am getting confused.  So my query grabs the image object which has a set<person> that is lazy loaded.  So it is basically an empty set when I ask for a specific image object?  I believe since I am using hibernateTemplate that the sessions is handled for me.  So when I do a hibernate.find("from Image ...) , I have to do another lookup for the person objects and populate that set?

Comment: If you are using Spring, take a look at the sections in the manual related to [transaction management with Hibernate (13.3.3, 13.3.4, and 13.3.5)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate). HibernateTemplate will open a Session if none exists, or use the existing Session if your method call is within a transaction. You are getting an error because you are accessing the Set after the Session is closed, which was possibly done automatically after the method call.